# NLTK / Python: Tokenising text to fixed token length

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to write a simple python script that imports a *.txt file and tokenises it using the NLTK module.

The challenge I have is that the complete corpus must be tokenised but each token must be less than or equal to 200 characters in length - is there a native function in the NLTK toolbox that would achieve this?

An example:
Tokenising the first couple of paragraphs to 'War and Peace' produces the following token which is 303 characters long

```
token = ["But I warn you, if you don't tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist--I really believe he is Antichrist--I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my 'faithful slave,' as you call yourself"]
```

It still contains punctuation (commas, hyphens) and I could write a function to break the sentence up using these types of break-points, my question is whether there is already native functionality in NLTK (or another language parser?) that would do this and handle corner cases effectively?

Comment: Can you give an example of a 200 character token? I don't think I've ever seen one that had more than 20 or 30 characters

Comment: I've added an example - to be clear the number of characters refers to the letters, not the words in the token (let me know if this isn't clear and I can edit the question)

Comment: Have you actually ran the code? I don't believe this is what the tokenizer does. It should be outputting `["But", "I", "warn"...]` with nltk, a token is a part of a sentence, so to say - or a word (but not always)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to only tokenize words that has less than 200 characters:

```
import nltk
with open('somefile.txt','r') as fp:
    tokenized_text = [word for word in nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(fp.read()) if len(word) <= 200]
```

It'll keep only the tokens that has less than or equal to 200 characters and discard the rest. If you need more Granularity of control, you might need to look into regular expression.
P.S. sorry if I misinterpret your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm not sure I made my question sufficiently clear, I need to tokenise the entire corpus and have ALL the tokens be less than 200 characters, not just keep the ones that meet the criteria :)